# Dynamic load next li after few seconds

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, dynamic-loading

I want to create a dynamic load a `ul` list.

For example, I have this `ul` list:

```
<section id="loadLi">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Now i want to load the `li` elements between 1 second, first `li` one, after 1 second, li two, after 1 second, li three... when the user is on the section (this code is at the middle of the body, so i want to load dinamically when the user scrolled to this part of the html).

Anyone knows how to do it?

P.D: I'm sorry about my english...i know it's really bad!

Comment: Do you have any attempts to do it? Also, where are you loading them from?

Comment: No, I'm trying to do it but I do not even know where to start. The ul list are static so, they don't come from any database or something.

Comment: Static? Check out my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this? Using `.delay()`?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#loadLi li").hide();
  $("#loadLi li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(1000 * i).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="loadLi">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I want, but do u know how to do this when the user scrolled to the section?

Comment: @AlexPerez You just need to bind an event to the `$(window).scroll()` and check the `$(window).scrollTop` value to be the offset.

Comment: Okey, i'm going to try it. Thank you so much!